# none subject -verb -agreement different answers

Tags: grammar

### Though many pages and books of grammar suggest using either singular or plural verb after ( none) yet many would use a plural verb only when the noun after ( of ) = plural

Blue Book grammar : If the object of the preposition is singular, use a singular verb. If the object of the preposition is plural, use a plural verb

Pop Quiz in the same page:

- None of the chairs was/were comfortable.

Pop Quiz answer:
None of the chairs were or was comfortable.
But here :  https://quizlet.com/438832873/chapter-6-flash-cards/

- None of the passengers __****are**** upset with the new regulation.

### As you see the only choice they suggest = plural verb

I don't know with whom, I would go.

Comment: I surely know when there is a pronoun referent plural in the sentence the only choice is to use a plural verb   Example : None of these swimmers wear (their) flippers in the pool.   2. when there is indefinite article is  used  the choice = singular verb  Example : None of these actors is an Oscar winner.

Answer (score 1):

> None of the passengers are upset with the new regulation.

The quiz is wrong. "Is" would also be acceptable in that sentence. ("Are" does sound slightly better to me, but both versions are equally correct.)

Comment: I was taught that _none_ is short for _not one_ and therefore takes a singular verb. I've since learned that it _is_ also acceptable to use the plural.